# Por que objeto não está sendo instanciado?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, java-ee, classes, instanciar-objeto

Tenho uma classe Bean (`Casa.java`)

```
public class Casa{
      //atribubutos

      private String parede;

      public Casa(){
      }
      //getters e setters
      public void setParede(String parede){
             this.parede = parede;
      }
      public String getParede(){
             return parede;
      }
}
```

Eu estou tentando instanciar ela em outra classe como no exemplo

```
public class testeCasa(){

       public static void main(String[] args){

          String erro="";
           try{
              Casa casa = new Casa();

              casa.setParede("Parede Sul");
              System.out.println(casa.getParede());
              }
           }catch (Exception e{

                  erro = e.getMessage();
           }finally{
                  System.out.println(erro);
           }
}
```

Só que hora que rodo o *debug*, ele chega no trecho `Casa casa = new Casa();`" e para o programa nem continua pro `casa.getParede();` e vai direto pro `finally` imprimindo o erro como "". O que pode ser?

Comment: Que erro aparece?

Comment: Talvez lhe falta fazer um `import endereco.do.pacote.Casa`. Mas é só um palpite, tem que postar o erro que você está recebendo.

Comment: fiz o import, ele nao aparece erro, o programa somente para e nada mais ocorre @Math

Comment: Se o código só faz isto mesmo que você posteou, não tem erro algum, ele não está fazendo nada útil, só isto. Ele executa direitinho, só que você não mandou fazer nada que possa ser verificado. Não podemos ajudar muito só com estas informações. Se o código estivesse completo, **talvez** ajudasse um pouco.

Comment: @bigown o codigo eh isso mesmo, os getters e setters sao padroes mesmo, ele simplesmente termina o programa sem pegar o get ou passar pra proxima linha do codigo depois de "Casa casa = new Casa()", tb to achando estranho isso mas é o que esta ocorrendo

Comment: Você está falando que o código é isso, mas fala que tem *getters* e *setters*, fala que tem mais linhas depois. Isso não bate. Pela sua descrição não está ocorrendo nada errado ou a pergunta não consegue mostrar qual é o problema.

Comment: @bigown coloquei o codigo inteiro e o que ocorre, ele nem vai setar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu código nem compila, então toda descrição da pergunta e dos comentários não são verdadeiros. Quando resolve-se os problemas que impedem a compilação o código funciona perfeitamente, apesar de não estar fazendo nada muito útil. Mas se o objetivo era atribuir uma valor para a propriedade e depois imprimi-lo pegando valor dela, isto está ocorrendo.

```
class Casa {
    private String parede;
    public void setParede(String parede) {
        this.parede = parede;
    }
    public String getParede() {
        return parede;
    }
}

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String erro="";
        try {
            Casa casa = new Casa();
            casa.setParede("Parede Sul");
            System.out.println(casa.getParede());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            erro = e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            System.out.println(erro);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yr5OBQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/agcocbol-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Instanciating.java).

O [construtor é absolutamente desnecessário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) neste caso. O `try-catch` também parece ser, mas pode estar querendo testar ou aprender algo com ele.